# How to permanently disable the tray in SWT TrayDialog?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

When `F1` is pressed the default behaviour of a [`TrayDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/TrayDialog.html) is to open the help tray (if not already opened), by calling `openTray()`. I don't want that behaviour (but I do want to use a `ElementTreeSelectionDialog`, which extends `TrayDialog`), and I don't know how to disable that.

I tried to add my own listener event filter for `SWT.KeyDown` and setting `event.type = SWT.NONE` inside my `handleEvent()` without success (my own event handler works, but also the tray is opened).

I also tried to override `openTray()` to do nothing, but then a NPE is thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.help.ui.internal.DefaultHelpUI.displayContextAsHelpTray(DefaultHelpUI.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.help.ui.internal.DefaultHelpUI.displayContext(DefaultHelpUI.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.help.ui.internal.DefaultHelpUI.displayContext(DefaultHelpUI.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.help.WorkbenchHelpSystem.displayContext(WorkbenchHelpSystem.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.help.WorkbenchHelpSystem$WorkbenchHelpListener.helpRequested(WorkbenchHelpSystem.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:153)
    ...
```

Any ideas? I'm using Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: What stack trace do you get for the NPE when you override `openTray`?

Comment: @greg-449 Stack trace added.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a way. I'm not sure if it's the recommended/clean/safe way, but in case it helps someone, this worked for me:

```
@Override
protected void configureShell(Shell shell) {
    super.configureShell(shell);
    shell.addHelpListener(new HelpListener() {
        @Override
        public void helpRequested(HelpEvent e) {
            // nothing to do
        }
    });
}
```